# Create fake $route inside data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to use a test-suite and inside my component, I'm using Vue-Router, thus I have `$route` object inside `data()` of my component.

For my test suite, I want to fake `$route` so I can access a fake value inside a component while testing rather than setting up Vue-Router.

When I try to use

```
data() {
    return {
        $route: { fullPath: '/' },
        test: 'test'
    }
}
```

I can't access $route using `this.$route` however I can access `this.test`. I think the `$` sign is causing this.

Is there a way to fake $route and be able to access it as `this.$route`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

For example:

```js
Vue.prototype.$route = { fullPath: '/' }

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    {{message}}
    Faker Full Path: {{$route.fullPath}}
</div>
```